# Using HTTPS for my entire Wordpress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, https

The website is regsitered and hosted by GoDaddy. I have already purchased and installed the standard SSL certificate and every Url of the WordPress admin backend as well as the frontend website are shown in HTTPS.

The only problem i face is at the extreme right section in the address bar of Google chrome, there is a grey shield icon which says -- " This page includes script from unauthenticated sources ", and it gives me an option to Load the unsafe script. Now how am i supposed to get rid of this message.

How do i ensure that every plugin, css and javascript url's follow the HTTPS path?

Comment: easiest is to make sure all of your templates are using protocol-relative urls: `//example.com/path/to/script.js`. Then it won't matter which protocol is used to hit your pages - the resource will be fetched using the same protocol as the containing page was.

Comment: any external files from CDNs? Check they are available over https

Comment: If security is your goal, I would advise not using CDNs and hosting your code locally. ;)

Comment: Well, the external files include.. font awesome icons from github, google web fonts and certain wordpress plugins like updraftPlus for backup and Wordpress SEO by Yoast!