# Is it safe to switch to https on a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I would like to get a SSL certificate for my WordPress site. Is it safe to switch from http to https? My host says it's an automatic install, but shouldn't I change all the URLs?

In my theme I have hard coded URLs, but also WordPress permalink PHP codes for example. The hard coded URLs can be changed, but how about the URLs in the Wordpress code itself and all the plugins? If I change that and there's an update it will all be lost I suppose.

I would like to have https all over the website. Will the site and all the plugins still work after I switch from http to https?

Comment: *"I would like to get a SSL certificate for my WordPress site"* - You might try [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) or [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). They offer free Class 1 server certificates. The certificates are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Class 1's are domain validated via email and *don't* allow wildcards. If you need a wildcard, then you'll have to purchase a Class 2 or higher. Startcom and CAcert charge for revocation, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Why is the question "Is it safe to switch to https on a Wordpress site?" not about programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe, but yes, you will have to change the hardcoded urls or establish redirections, the first option is better. There are plugins that help you with this, remember all internal linking in your posts has to change, too.

You can read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). [This question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099012/using-https-for-my-entire-wordpress-website?rq=1).

Comment: I can change all the hard coded URLs in my theme, but I can't do that for the plugins and the Wordpress installation files, because they'll change when updated. Is it enough to only change the URLs in my theme? I'll look into the pages you suggested.

Comment: Plugins shouldn't be using hardcoded urls. For wordpress files don't worry, you just have to change this in the configuration panel: WordPress Address and Site Address.

If you end up locked out of your panel, dont worry, you always can edit your wp-config.php and add these lines:  

`define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');`  and  `define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');`

Comment: Thanks! I think I know enough now to switch to https.

Comment: @edow, you can always ask your hosting for support

Comment: Thanks, it's working already. Had to modify the config file, but further it worked immediately.